# I'm not complaining, in fact I think it is funny, but why was my flag denied?

Tags: discussion

This question asking the purpose of a [criss-crossed elastic strap](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/8908/what-do-you-call-the-criss-crossed-elastic-strap-on-this-northface-backpack/20529#20529) elicited this answer:

> to put the jars filled with the blood of your enemies.

which I flagged as

> Repulsive and smart-alecky answer that answers nothing.

**The flag was denied.**     **????**

If I had been more lady-like, would the flag have been accepted?  Or was it a question of timing?  The answer was deleted 1 hour 11 min after I flagged it.

Comment: I'd assume because it's something that the community can handle themselves (hint: "not an answer" flag, or might even be "rude" flag), and doesn't really need *mods* intervention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the record, your flag, as well as quite a few others on that post were all marked as helpful.

It was not declined.

Comment: Sorry, Rory, my mind must be going.